# Cabal: conditionally override a flag default value

Tags: haskell, overriding, conditional-statements, cabal, compiler-flags

Is there any way to rewrite either:

```
flag llvm
    description: compile via LLVM
    default    : if os(mingw32)
                   False
                 else
                   True
```

or

```
flag llvm
    description: compile via LLVM
    default    : True

if os(mingw32)
    ?SET-LLVM=False?
```

and get `cabal` to work with it?

---

**Note:**

Further down in the same file the `llvm` flag is used like:

```
if flag(llvm)
  ghc-options: -fllvm -optlo-O3
```

and there are many other single high-level flags that translate to multiple `ghc-options` entries, such as `static` to `-static -optl-static`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
flag llvm
    description: compile via LLVM
    default    : True

-- ...

Executable foo
    if flag(llvm) && !os(windows)
        ghc-options: -fllvm -optlo-O3
```

Comment: Now I can't `-fllvm` on Windows.  =[