# Conditional selection of integer simple in Stack

Tags: haskell, licensing, haskell-stack

Due to licensing constraints, we need to use the `integer-simple` variant of GHC when compiling in Windows platforms. Currently this is specified in our [`stack.yaml`](https://github.com/TorXakis/TorXakis/blob/develop/stack.yaml) file:

```
ghc-variant: integersimple
# ...
extra-deps:
- text-1.2.2.1
# Override default flag values for local packages and extra-deps
flags: 
  text: 
    integer-simple: true
```

However, this won't work on Linux.

It'd be nice a way to conditionally include the code above depending on the host architecture. Is there a way of doing this using stack, and if not, how would you go about solving this problem?

The only alternative I can think about right now is having two stack files, but I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523935/cabal-conditionally-override-a-flag-default-value

Comment: I saw that one as well. I wonder whether it is possible to specify in cabal that I need to depend on the `integer-simple` variant of `text` (like I'm doing in stack above).

Comment: I assume you've considered a custom `Setup.hs`, but would prefer a simpler approach?

Comment: Seems like the capabilities you want are divided between `.cabal` and `.yaml`. I've run into this issue a few times and it's really annoying.

Comment: I also found this: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2048

Comment: I haven't considered a custom setup, so that could be an option.

Comment: TLDR: It doesn't seem to be possible at present, because `.cabal` doesn't allow passing on flags to packages (although you *can* do so via the command line) and `.yaml` doesn't allow conditionals at present. I'll write up an answer so we can wrap this one up. I *think* I've done my due diligence.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR**: Use a custom `Setup.hs`.

It doesn't seem to be possible at present, because `.cabal` doesn't allow passing on flags to packages (although you can do so via the command line) and `.yaml` doesn't allow conditionals at present<sup>1</sup>.

---

**1.** I find the stack and cabal documentation kind of obtuse and disorganised. Add to that the fact that the API seems to change rather often, and it becomes rather easy to see how one might overlook some feature that might solve your problem. Keep an eye open.